# How to differentiate a request for an image embedded on page from a direct request for an image

Tags: php, asp.net, html

Is there a way, on the server, to tell if a request for an image like:

```
http://www.myserver.com/test.jpg
```

is a direct request (entered in browser address bar), or as a result of an image tag?

```
<img src="http://www.myserver.com/test.jpg" alt="blah blah">
```

Comment: As the answers say, you can't, but if there is a specific reason to do that there may be a work around. What do you need that for?

Comment: If the image is not found on the server, I want to return 404 in the case that it was embedded, and redirect to a new page in the case that it was a direct request.

Comment: Removed comment, read it the wrong way round, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the `Referer` field in the request to identify whether or not the image was requested directly or was referred by another page; however, this won't allow you to differentiate between an **embedded** image and a **linked** image.

Edit: Also, as noted by tmuguet, it is extremely easy to spoof or obscure the referer in a request.

Comment: Furthermore, the `Referer` cannot be fully trusted, as it can easily be forged.

Comment: @AntP I think the whole 'Referer' part of the answer can be omitted as it does not assist in any way to the question

Comment: @thaJeztah - it does address the question. It gives a best-guess alternative to a problem that can't be solved directly, which is where simply saying 'no', falls short.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to differentiate. Both will be requested by the browser in the same way